# Sign in with Apple Custom button

Tags: ios, apple-sign-in, sign-in-with-apple

I am using Sign in with apple in my iOS application. I want to localise the language of the button title according to locale. It's working for the languages which are supported by apple, but is it possible to localise the button title when the locale language is a non-apple supported language.

eg: Lithuanian language, it's not supported by apple. While using this language, the system language will be english.

I just read about the custom Apple sign in button option, is this kind of localisation is possible in custom button ? or any other way to tackle this!!

Comment: I think you should go for custom button. There title can be localised.

Comment: Yes, It's worked and approved.. Thank you

Comment: Please make right tick on my answer as it worked for you. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go with custom button, It will surely help.

1. You can customised custom button in any manner.